# What alternative to DUnit with C++ Builder?

Tags: c++, unit-testing, c++builder, xunit, dunit

I have some projects developed with **C++ builder XE**.
I would like to add some unit test, but the **DUnit** framework installed is nice for Delphi, but the integration with C++ builder is not so good (and very limited).

What other xUnit framework can I easily work with ?

Comment: DUnit is the Delphi version of JUnit, CPPUnit is the C++ version of the same framework

Comment: @Petesh How about the integration of CPPUnit in C++ builder ?

Comment: stuck back in the past with 2010 and not XE - I'm not familiar with the features that provide integration with the UI - I just run the tests in a command line window in the background continually

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your case I'd start by asking Embarcadero for assistance.  They want to fully support the developers who use their stuff, and automated unit testing is really critical to keeping them happy.

Until then, CppUnit works on any C++ code, but does not really integrate all that well with IDEs.  The approach we've used is to create a new project to contain the tests, and have its linker include the path to the existing production project's .OBJ files.  We set up a a project dependency so the test project depends on the production project.

In the Test project, we'll use different main.cpp files, one each for Debug and Release, and use conditionals to include/exclude the appropriate one from the Debug and Release builds.

For some "fake" integration, at least as far as running the tests go, in the DebugMain.cpp we'll load up the MFC TestRunner GUI, so the developer can click to select the tests they want to execute.  In the ReleaseMain.cpp, we'll use the command line test runner, using the CompilerOutputter object which will let the build process know of success or failure.  The output is also compatible with IDEs that interpret stuff like that, so you can click on a failed test report in the Output window, and the IDE takes you to the failing test assertion.